# GreaseMonkey editing Page

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

How can I change a page with this html code :

```
   <tr>
    <td nowrap title="7884">Ontem foi dia de</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">6,0</td></tr>
   <tr>
```

to this one using greasemonkey :

```
    <tr>
    <td title="7884" nowrap="nowrap">ontem foi dia de</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td title="aprovadissimo" align="center" bgcolor="#ff8888">A</td>
    <td title="Treze" align="center" bgcolor="#88ff88">13</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td bgcolor="#88ff88">Aprovado</td>
    <td align="right">6,0</td></tr>
   <tr>
```

Comment: You don't provide any code to work with and you don't specify how each column needs to be recognized. Your solution is a simple search and replace.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/ and see about writing GreaseMoney Scripts

Comment: tahts the first thing I did but no luck

Answer (score -1):

How are you determining which table cells should have which certain values in them? What are the rules you're going to have for this?

Comment: How about use comments to ask such questions?

Comment: what ? I just want to change them no rules.